# Searching through large int arrays in Java

Tags: java, arrays

I am new to programming and currently doing Java as my first introductory course. Below is an exercise I have been struggling with over the past week, but couldn't figure out how to go about it. Can someone please assist? Thanks

You are asked to write a program that mimics a mailman conducting an experiment in flipping mailboxes.

A flip means opening a mailbox if it is closed, and closing a mailbox if it is open.

There are 100 mailboxes numbered 1 to 100 that are all initially closed. In the first step, visiting every mailbox (i.e. mailboxes 1, 2, 3, ..., 100), he flips them all. Then in the second step, visiting every second mailbox (i.e. mailboxes 2, 4, 6, ..., 100), he flips them. Then in the third step, visiting every third mailbox (i.e. mailboxes 3, 6, 9, ..., 99), he flips them. In this manner he goes in steps of 4, 5, ..., 10,...,50, and finally 100, wherein he directly goes to the 100th mailbox and flips it.

At the end of this process, which mailboxes are open? Hint: Set up an array of Booleans all initialized to false representing closed mailboxes. Then, in steps of 1, 2, 3, …, 100 go through the sequence of mailboxes and toggle them. In the end, print out the mailbox numbers that are open (have the value true).

Hi All,
Thanks a million for your guidance. Below is what I have been able to do. Unfortunately, I realize I may have to repeat this process up to the 99th index if I continue this way. Is there a more efficient way to do it, please?

```
 public class Assignment {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
    int index;
    boolean mailBoxes[] = new boolean[100];

    //flip each mailbox

    for(index=0; index<mailBoxes.length;index++){
    mailBoxes[index] = !mailBoxes[index];
    System.out.println(mailBoxes[index]);
    }

    for(index=1; index<mailBoxes.length;index+=2){
    mailBoxes[index] = !mailBoxes[index];
    System.out.println(mailBoxes[index]);
    }

    for(index=2; index<mailBoxes.length;index+=3){
    mailBoxes[index] = !mailBoxes[index];
    System.out.println(mailBoxes[index]);
    }
```

Comment: Where exactly are you having problems?

Comment: boolean [] mailBoxes = new boolean [100]; - default is false

Comment: The title of your question shows that you should re-read your assignment. You don't need to search anything, and you shouldn't use an int array, but a boolean array.

Comment: @JBNizet you could use an int array and each individual bit is the status of a mailbox. TBH the JIT might actually replace boolean arrays with a bitmap.

Comment: @Smith_61 but that would make things harder, and wouldn't respect the indications of the assignment.

Comment: @JBNizet The only time a boolean array is mentioned is in the hint part. Actually a Boolean array which isn't even a primitive. Which means it isn't required to complete the assignment, just that's the easiest way. I always liked implementing assignments in uncommon ways, if nothing more than to spice up a grader's day.

Answer (score 1):

Since it's an assignment, i won't write any actual code for you, but some `pseudo-code`.

How i would do it: Since the requirement doesn't specify anything else, than the open-close state of the mailboxes, a `boolean` (`true` or `false`) array would be perfectly fine.

Then you could do the flipping in the following manner:

```
for i=1 to 100 increment by 1
   flip(mailboxes, i)
end
```

The flipping of every second:

```
for i=2 to 100 increment by 2
   flip(mailboxes, i)
end
```

So you might as well do every first, second, third... flipping in another loop:

```
for j=1 to 4 increment by 1
    for i=j to 100 increment by j
        flip(mailboxes, i)
    end
end
```

The outer loop would go from `1 to 4`, and the inner loop could use `j` as the start of the iteration as well as the increment value.

The `flip` functions responsibility would be to set the value of the input boolean array to the opposite:

```
function flip(array, index)
    array[index] = !array[index]
end
```

If you like the idea, here are the docs that will help you in the actual implementation:

- [For loop](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/for.html) - The actual java syntax for for loops
- [Arrays](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/arrays.html) - How arrays work

Answer (score 0):

You may try using two list for tracking the mail status.

```
List<MailId> read;
List<MailId> unread;
```

When user flips mail to read, then move the MailId from unread to read list and vice-versa.

Answer (score 0):

To try and get you started, you're going to need a `boolean` array which represents the mailboxes...`boolean` is either `true` (lets say open) or `false` (lets say closed).

```
boolean[] mailBoxes = new boolean[100];
```

The nice thing about this, is all the elements in the array are automatically set to `false`!

Start by taking a closer look at [the Arrays trail](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/arrays.html) for more details.

Next, you're going to need some way to visit each mailbox, now, there are plenty of ways you might do this, but for simplicity, you can use a `for-next-loop`

```
for (int index = 0; index < mailBoxes.length; index++) {
    //...
}
```

Take a look at [The for Statement](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/for.html) for more details...

Then you need some way to change the state of each mailbox as you visit it, that is, change the assigned value...again, there are multiple ways to do this...

You could, use an `if-else` statement

```
if (mailBoxes[index]) { // is true
    mailBoxes[index] = false;
} else {
    mailBoxes[index] = true;
}
```

Or you could, more simply, just flip the value using a `!` (not) operator...

```
mailBoxes[index] = !mailBoxes[index];
```

This just says that `mailBoxes[index]` is not what ever `mailBoxes[index]` currently is, this will have the nice effect of turning `true` into `false` and visa-versa...

Now, the complex part is, you're going to need to use at least three `for-next` loops, all with different incrementers...this is why I suggested a `for-next-loop`

For example, the second loop might look something like...

```
for (int index = 0; index < mailBoxes.length; index += 2) {
```

This should give a push in the right direction...

Also, don't forget to make use of lots of `System.out.println` statements to check what's going on ;)

Answer (score 0):

As stated above, most of the solution is already hinted.

```
//You can use just an array of boolean (which by default inits to false):
boolean[] b = new boolean[100];

//then insert loop for steps (which are incremented from 1 to 50 as it seems)
for (int step=1;step<=50;step++){
     //then loop over array elements using current step
     for(int j=0;j<b.length;j+=step){
         //flip mailbox using 'not' operator
         b[j]=!b[j];
     }
     //you can also print results to System.out to debug
}
```

Note that there's nonstandard step=100 (flip only last) which probably you can do manually.

If you are new to java, take care of zero-based indexing, i.e. 1st mailbox is actually b[0] (or boxes.get(0) if you will be using an ArrayList).
Also it would be good to modify code in some way (more than required by the task) to get a better understanding of finer details.

Comment: My understanding if that he must loop from 1 to 100, not from 1 to 50. *Then, in steps of 1, 2, 3, …, 100*.

Comment: Well, I don't know. The description is a bit vague. One time it says:
_In this manner he goes in steps of 4, 5, ..., 10,...,50, and finally 100, wherein he directly goes to the 100th mailbox and flips it._
Also the way boxes are flipped on the 100th step is different, hence my understanding of loop 1:50, then one step of 100. Yup, weird. Maybe I'm mistaken.
But then what the difference of stepping with step=51 and step=52 ?

Comment: I was under the impression you went through the array 'length' times using a step from 1 to 'length'. I also took it to mean you start at 'step' and advance 'step' indices each loop. You could go to 'length/2' and then finally loop through the last half of the array flipping each mailbox. Should achieve the same output.

Comment: Actually yes, if we go for _step_ loop from 1 to length, it is essentially the same as _step_ loop from 1 to [length/2], then flip last box. At least when boxes length is even. But that is an extra information for better understanding of the task posing.